# How to handle user actions (clicks etc.) BEFORE JS has loaded on a JS-only site (like Facebook etc.)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

The situation is:

My client has a heavy javascript/jquery based website (usage with deactived js is not possible). Usually it takes up to 7 secs until JS is loaded and initialized. Problem is: A lot of people do actions/click on things before JS is initialized, which leads to masses of complainments from the users, a la "nothing happens when i click there".

**My question: Is there a best practice to avoid this / how to init js as early as possible ?**

Popular site with same problem: Facebook was suffering from this issue too, but have dropped the js-init time to ~2 secs on mainstream devices, which is, from a usability point of view, totally acceptable.

Comment: You could use a full screen semi-transparent overlay with a loading message which fades out on init. The best way would be to refactor the JS so that all the initial functions/event handlers load first then the other scripts are loaded via ajax in the background.

Comment: I agree with Joe.  Also, a full 7 seconds is a really long time.  I have written single page applications that relied completely on JS and they didn't take nearly as long.  Can't you progressively load only the methods you need as you need them?

Comment: Is it 7 seconds because of the time for the JS transfer? Or because it really needs 7 seconds to execute the init functions? Either way, using an async modular definition (AMD), see requireJS maybe.

Comment: @Salketer 7secs because of downloading the files.

Comment: You might want to do like we did then. We are providing a SaaS solution that requires a login. So we load all the JS files on the login page while the user enters his information, that way, once the application launches the files are already in the cache. You might be able to do the same